# For which real number $\alpha$ is there a value $c$ for which $\int^c_0 \frac{1}{1+x^\alpha}dx=\int^\infty_c\frac{1}{1+x^\alpha}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For which real number $\alpha$ is there a value $c$ for which $\displaystyle\int^c_0 \frac{1}{1+x^\alpha}\mathrm{d}x=\int^\infty_c\frac{1}{1+x^\alpha}\mathrm{d}x$.

**What I have tried:**

Since when $0\leq x\leq c$ , $\displaystyle0\leq \frac{1}{1+x^\alpha} \leq 1$ for all $\alpha$, so $\displaystyle \int^c_0 \frac{1}{1+x^\alpha}\mathrm{d}x$ converge.
when  $c\leq x$, when $\alpha<1$, $\displaystyle \int^\infty_c\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ converge, when $\alpha\geq 1$, $\displaystyle \int^\infty_c\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ diverge. So only when $\alpha<1$, the existence of such a $c$ is possible.

I don't know what to do from here, and there's a hint to use the intermediate value theorem.
Then $\displaystyle\int^c_0 \frac{1}{1+x^\alpha}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{c}{1+t{_1}{^\alpha}}, 0<t_1<c$, $\displaystyle \int^m_c\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{m-c}{1+t{_2}{^\alpha}}, m\to\infty, c<t_2<m$. It doesn't look promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any fixed $\alpha$, the expression $f_\alpha(c) = \int_0^c \frac{1}{1 + x^\alpha}dx$ is a continuous (and differentiable!), strictly increasing function of $c$ for $c\geq 0$.
Additionally, note that the equation in the problem statement is equivalent to
$$f_\alpha(c)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^\alpha}dx$$
and thus by the intermediate value theorem, there exists a root whenever $\alpha$ is such that the integral converges, since $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{c\to\infty}f(c)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^\alpha}dx$.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that $\int_0^c\frac{dX}{1+x^\alpha}$ converges for all $c>0$ and has some limit $L<\infty$ for $c\rightarrow\infty$. Then since integrals are (uniformly) continuous in their bounds, clearly by the IVT there's a $c$ such that both integrals in question equal $L/2$ simultaneously .

Comment: @BarryCipra: Yep.